# use name_repair for mids object in mice

Tags: r, lme4, r-mice, r-colnames, lmertest

I have a set of 5 datasets that were generated through multiple imputation using the mice package. I'm running a hierarchical regression on these datasets, but when I try to pool the results, I get an error that "Column 6 must be named" and to use .name_repair. I've never seen this issue, and I checked the names of my columns, and they all have a name. Can someone explain what I should do to troubleshoot?

```
pool(with(mids_dis, lmer(exer_vig ~ 1 + (1 | team_num) + (1 | dept_client))))

Error: Column 6 must be named.
Use .name_repair to specify repair.
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
> rlang::last_error()
<error>
message: Column 6 must be named.
Use .name_repair to specify repair.
class:   `rlang_error`
backtrace:
  1. mice::pool(...)
  2. mice:::pool.fitlist(getfit(object), dfcom = dfcom)
  4. mice:::summary.mira(fitlist, type = "tidy", exponentiate = FALSE)
  8. base::lapply(fitlist, tidy, effects = "fixed", ...)
 10. broom:::tidy.merMod(X[[i]], ...)
 11. broom::fix_data_frame(ret, newnames = nn)
 13. tibble:::as_tibble.data.frame(ret)
 14. tibble:::as_tibble.list(unclass(x), ..., .rows = .rows, .name_repair = .name_repair)
 15. tibble:::lst_to_tibble(x, .rows, .name_repair, col_lengths(x))
 16. tibble:::set_repaired_names(x, .name_repair)
 21. tibble:::repaired_names(names(x), .name_repair = .name_repair)
 22. tibble:::check_unique(new_name)
Call `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full backtrace
```

Comment: Witthout a reproducible e.g. it is difficult to test.  By checking the `?pool` e.g and a one created with `lmer`, it is working for me `imp <- mice(nhanes, maxit = 2, m = 2);fit <- with(data = imp, exp = lmer(bmi ~1 + (1 | hyp) + (1 | chl)));summary(pool(fit))#   estimate std.error statistic       df     p.value
(Intercept) 26.84527  1.495867   17.9463 1.688993 0.006303523`

Comment: Please include minimal sample data with which we can reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching, I found the answer to my issue here:

https://github.com/stefvanbuuren/mice/issues/95

In short, mice throws the name_repair error when using lmerTest. There are two ways to get around this error:

If you do NOT need significance (p) values, then loading lme4 or using lme4::lmer will work with no issues.

If you DO need significance values, then you need to also load the package **miceadds**. With this loaded, you can use lmerTest with no issue.

```
library(mice)
library(miceadds)
library(lmerTest)

summary(pool(with(mids_dis, lmerTest::lmer(exer_vig ~ 1 + age + (1 | team_num) + (1 | dept_client)))))

              estimate  std.error statistic       df      p.value
(Intercept) 2.36102939 0.31957622  7.388001 244.3050 2.353007e-12
age         0.01096181 0.01042713  1.051277 238.7271 2.941943e-01
```